# NodeJS: Keep same Chrome DevTools URL whenever running with --inspect

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, v8

Whenever I run a NodeJS project using --inspect flag it generates a new URL with a path that ends with an UUID as in the example bellow:

> chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=127.0.0.1:9229/**c6a9cbe1-cdfc-4981-8520-3489c9031c0d**

Is there a way to not change the UUID whenever running node with the --inspect flag or any other way to keep the Chrome DevTools session open from one run to the other?

Comment: [Reuse/restart the same node inspect session](//stackoverflow.com/q/42340319) ?

Comment: @wOxxOm that answers my question!